# Graceful way of cleaning objects in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Currently I am developing a class which abstracts the SQLAlchemy. This class will act as helper tool to verify the values from database. This class will be used in regression/load test. Test cases will make hundred-thousands of database query. The layout of my class is as following.

```
class MyDBClass:
    def __init__(self, dbName)
         self.dbName = dbName
         self.dbEngines[dbName] = create_engine()
         self.dbMetaData[dbName] = MetaData()
         self.dbMetaData[dbName].reflect(bind=self.dbEngines[dbName])
         self.dbSession[dbName] = sessionmaker(bind=self.dbEngines[dbName])

    def QueryFunction(self,dbName, tablename, some arguments):
          session = self.dbSession[dbName]()
          query = session.query(requiredTable)
          result = query.filter().all()
          session.close()
    def updateFunction(self, dbName, talbeName, some arguments):
          session = self.dbSession[dbName]()
          session.query(requiredTable).filter().update()
          session.commit()
          session.close()
    def insertFunction(self, dbName, tableName, some arguments):
          connection = self.dbEngines[dbName].connect()
          requiredTable = self.dbMetaData[dbName].tables[tableName]
          connection.execute(requiredTable.insert(values=columnValuePair))
          connection.close()
    def cleanClose(self):
          # Code which will remove the connection/session/object from memory.
          # do some graceful work to clean close.
```

I want to write cleanClose() method which should remove the object which might be created by this class. This method should remove all those object from memory and provide a clean close. This may also avoid the memory leak. 
I am not able to figure out what all object should be removed from the memory. Can some one suggest me what method calls I need to make here?

### Edit1:

Is there any way by which I can measure the performance different method and their variant?
I was going through the [documentation here](http://sqlalchemy-stage.readthedocs.org/en/latest/orm/session.html?highlight=session#sqlalchemy.orm.session) and realized that I should not make session in every method rather I should create single instance of session and use throughout. Please provide your feedback on this. And let me know what would be the best way of doing thing here.

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated here.

Comment: From which programming language are you coming into python?

Comment: I have C, C++ and java programming language.
@Van I would also like to ask the programming pattern which I have used here. Is it correct way of doing?

Comment: I am very new to Python programming and I hardly know about it.

Comment: You should post your actual code - it's obvious the code above won't run because you have function arguments that aren't used in the methods and the methods refer to variables that don't appear to exist.

Comment: Please start with the [Object Relational Tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/tutorial.html). Go through many examples on the SA website and try to understand them. Also here [SO sqlalchemy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlalchemy) questions often contain complete working scripts of code (both in question and answers). And I definitely would not start tackling *optimization* related questions before you are comfortable with building proper object model and making it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove objects from memory in Python, you just need to stop referencing them. There is not usually any need to explicitly write or call any methods to destroy or clean up the objects. So, an instance of `MyDBClass` will be automatically cleaned up when it goes out of scope.

If you are talking about closing down an SQLAlchemy session, then you just need to call the close() method on it.

An SQLAlchemy session is designed for multiple transactions. You don't generally need to create and destroy it multiple times. Create one session in the `__init__` function and then use that in `QueryFunction`, `updateFunction`, etc.

Comment: thank for providing your input.  Probably I am confuse here. Doesn't this line create a session?  
`self.dbSession[dbName] = sessionmaker(bind=self.dbEngines[dbName])`
Or can you tell me the difference between these two lines.
`self.dbSession[dbName] = sessionmaker(bind=self.dbEngines[dbName])
` and `session = self.dbSession[dbName]()` ?

Comment: Calling sessionmaker, despite the name, doesn't appear to actually create a session - it creates a Session class. So you need to create the session itself in the `__init__` as well, ie. the first line of each of your query and update functions. (I don't know why your insert function doesn't use the session - it should.)

Comment: Since I am new to python and sqlalchemy, I may ask some naive questions. Please bear with me.
 Can you please tell me how to use session for insert operation?

Comment: Create the object (as you would a normal Python object), then use the session's `add()` method to add it. http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/session.html